# How do I check for validation for redirection to void cyclic redirection loop in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a redirection model with two columns `to` and `from`. I also have a frontend UI, where the redirections can be added.

I need to know whether is there any solution to avoid cyclic redirect loop by creating a before_save validation or some thing else.

Some of the redirection test cases:

Cyclic redirection (**will cause a redirection loop**)

```
1 -> 2
2 -> 3
3 -> 4

4 -> 1
```

Chained redirection (**will not cause a redirection loop**)

```
1 -> 2
2 -> 3

4 -> 1
```

Cyclic redirection (**will cause redirection loop**)

```
1 -> 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Redirection < ApplicationRecord
...

validate :to_and_from_not_equal
validate :check_redirection_loop

private

def to_and_from_not_equal
  if self.to == self.from
    errors.add(:base, "To and From cannot be equal")
  end
end

def check_redirection_loop
  if to_exist_in_from? && from_exist_in_to?
    errors.add(:base, "This redirection causes redirection loop")
  end
end

def to_exist_in_from?
  Redirection.where(to: self.from).present?
end

def from_exist_in_to?
  Redirection.where(from: self.to).present?
end
```

This is the answer extending @Maxence's answer. This works for me now. There can be improvements in the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, basically you don't want that the columns to and from be the same. It is very easy to do such a thing. In your redirection model, you can add :

```
class Redirection < ApplicationRecord
...

validate :to_and_from_not_equal

private

def to_and_from_not_equal
  if self.to == self.from
    errors.add(:base, "To and From cannot be equal")
  end
end
```

Then you cannot create your Redirection record if both values are equal.

Comment: Yes. This would work for a single redirection record with same `to` and `from`. I need to validate if another redirection record cause a redirection loop. I'll updated the question as it was not specific.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. But I am not sure this can be done with a simple snippet of code. Also, when a redirection happens to create a loop, what should be the solution to fix this issue ? Just preventing the user to create the record ? Also "to" and "from" are they URL like I assumed in my answer ?

Comment: Yeah, I know that this validation will not be simple. The possible solution is to prevent user from submitting the record and return an error. Also, the `to` and `from` are just the pathname like `/public`. The redirection is done using using the react-router-dom.
A possible validation idea is to use BFS to check whether the current redirection record will make a cyclic graph or sort.  But I don't know how to implement this in rails. I assumed there would be a rails gem or in-build method which will raise an error, as the redirection loop can crash the application.

Comment: I have found a better way to solve this. ```def check_redirection_loop
      if Redirection.find_by(to: self.from).present?
        if Redirection.find_by(from: self.to).present?
          errors.add(:base, "This redirection cause a redirect loop")
        end
      end
    end
```. But I don't know whether is this the rails way to do the ActiveRecordQuery?